# How do I add an attribute in an anchor tag?

Tags: 8

I want to make a module which will add some attributes in an anchor tag, whether the user adds in CKEditor or it is from Drupal menu system, before rendering it to the browser.

I can do it through jQuery with `$('a').attr('data-anchor', 'arial');`, but is there any way to do it through a module?

Comment: I think you mean through PHP? Because you can add your jQuery to your module and make file.js load on every page or on specific pages.

Comment: Yes, I want to do through PHP because jQuery may increase the rendering time.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using [hook_link_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Menu!menu.api.php/function/hook_link_alter/8.2.x)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_link_alter().
 */
function mymodule_link_alter(&$variables) {

    $variables['options']['attributes'] = array('data-anchor' => 'arial');

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think this might not work in my case. I want to alter all anchor tag whether the user added through CKEditor or rendering through a block like <a href="https://example.com">Hello<./a>. I don't think this hook will call for anchor tag that defined in content.

Comment: After testing, yes that's correct, this does not work with CKEditor. I would stick to the jQuery method, a few lines of jQuery will not slow you down.

Comment: @AkashJain, that's a different question. You need a text filter. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/filter-api/overview. The last link on this page has a good tutorial.

Comment: @4k4 is correct, even if you manually type in CKEditor `<a href="/node/1" data-anchor="arial">link</a>` the `data-anchor="arial"` part gets filtered out, removed. So I guess you need to create a text filter so it allows it.

Comment: ... allow it or add it for all links.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering some function where I got whole DOM structure but nevermind I will do it though Text filter. Thanks @4k4

Comment: Yes, if you want to add attributes in a text filter you can use the DOM structure of the field content, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208445/ckeditor-and-site-style